# CKEditor Testing: JEST ESM Modules - cannot use import statement

Tags: angular, jestjs, nrwl-nx, babel-jest

Summary

- Currently using nrwl/nx to manage a Angular mono repository.
- Upgrading from Angular 14 -> 15
- upgrading to jest 29 via nx (previous version was 27)
- attempts to run tests are failing for any modules that are ESM modules. i.e. Ckeditor. ngxcharts
- this was previously working with jest27 through the use of `transformIgnorePatterns` in `jest.config.ts`

Creating a standalone component that imports the CKEditorModule as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'ckeditor-test-rich-text-standalone',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CKEditorModule],
  template: ``,
  styles: [`    
  `]
})
export class RichTextStandaloneComponent {}
```

If I run `nx text rich-text` on this workspace, I get the following error.

```
 C:\...\node_modules\@ckeditor\ckeditor5-watchdog\src\editorwatchdog.js:12
import { throttle, cloneDeepWith, isElement } from 'lodash-es';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  2 | import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
> 3 | import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
    | ^
  4 |
  5 | @Component({
  6 |   selector: 'ckeditor-test-rich-text-standalone',
```

There are several issues around that identify the root cause as JEST no support esm Modules. and the general consensus seems to be that babel is required to transform these files.

Previously in jest 27, my `transformIgnorePatterns` allowed me to work around this issue, but this no longer seems to be working with jest 29. however this no longer seems to be the case

JEst has also apparently rolled out an experimental support for this via setting options

- `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`

however my attempts at setting this flag when running tests doesn't produce any difference in result. i.e.

- `nx test rich-text --watch NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`

here is my jest.config.ts where transformIgnorePatterns for ckeditor used to work in Jest 27. but no longer does in 29.

```
export default {
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  displayName: 'hello-world',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/hello-world',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js)$': 'babel-jest',
    'node_modules/@ckeditor/.+\.(js|ts)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html|svg)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!(.*.mjs)|(lodash-es)|(@ckeditor/.+\.js))',
    '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$'
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ]
};
```

my babel.config.js file. I saw some comments that some people were having issues if they used the .babelrc instead of the config file. so that doesn't seem like the cause.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [ [ '@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current', } } ] ]
};
```

I appreciate any assistance someone can provide to shed light on this issue as I've been struggling with it for a few days now.

thank you.

PS: Here is a [Link](https://github.com/mwamufiya/ckeditor-test2) to a very simple workspace where this is reproducible with a newly created NX workspace, angular 15, jest 29

my package.json dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~15.2.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^5.2.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "^36.0.1",
"@nrwl/angular": "15.8.5",
"babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.12.0"
```

my peer dependencies

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.0",
"@angular-devkit/core": "~15.2.0",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "~15.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~15.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~15.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~15.0.0",
"@angular/cli": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~15.2.0",
"@nrwl/cypress": "15.8.5",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.8.5",
"@nrwl/jest": "15.8.5",
"@nrwl/js": "15.8.5",
"@nrwl/linter": "15.8.5",
"@nrwl/workspace": "15.8.5",
"@schematics/angular": "~15.2.0",
"@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
"@types/node": "16.11.7",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
"cypress": "^12.2.0",
"eslint": "~8.15.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
"jest": "^29.4.1",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
"jest-preset-angular": "~13.0.0",
"nx": "15.8.5",
"prettier": "^2.6.2",
"ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
"ts-node": "10.9.1",
"typescript": "~4.9.5"
```